# Angular Material 2 Input style (single element/page)

Tags: angular, angular-material2

Is it possible to change the style (text color, placeholder color, underline color, etc) for a single Input element? I can style the remainder according to a global style, but what if you want to set the theme specifically on a single page or for a single control? What is the best practice for this?

For example, how do I style this block so that the placeholder, text and accent colors are all custom?

```
<md-input-container>
  <input mdInput placeholder="Email address">
</md-input-container>
```

Comment: you should be capable of handling with themes in material.

Comment: @Roman C Let's remember that SO is about answering questions and spreading knowledge, not just telling people it can't be done.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question. @ender

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define a custom theme for each material component and you should be able to override your base theme for the component in question like so:

```
@import '~/@angular/material/input/input-theme'
.custom-input {
  @include mat-input-theme($custom-input-theme)
}
```

Then just add the class to the `<md-input-container>`.

Also, if you are defining the custom class in a component's stylesheet, make sure the encapsulation is set to none:

```
@Component({
  ...
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
```